# How to use Server2012 as DHCP and on the same time Ubuntu Server as Gateway for the client Machines?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, gateway, dhcp-server

I want to use Windows Server 2012 R2 as a DHCP for the client computers with Ubuntu server acting as gateway to the internet.
I am using VMWare WorkStation. Both machines are installed on it.
Windows Server has IP Address "192.168.10.100" and Ubuntu Server's IP Address is "192.168.10.1". IP Pool for clients is "192.168.10.20 - 150".

Answer (score 2):

Just use the DHCP management console to set the router that is set in the DHCP responses (to the address of the Linux server).